# A tutorial to learn how to add 3d effects to a logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, tutorial

I am a beginner computer artist.

I am just learning Photoshop and Illustrator, but I am planning to do a logo/web site design with both.

I want to draw a logo for an application.

I can draw a simple logo like this one:

[image: simple superman logo]

I want to add a 3d effect to a logo, so that the result looks similar to this (effect-wise):

[image: 3d superman logo]

Please point me to a tutorial that teaches me how to add these kind of effects to a logos. A paid video tutorials are fine too.

Comment: For best results you'd have to more or less "paint" it. Just pen tool and maybe little dodge tool and of course brush tool.

Comment: To prove my point I made my own _pretty_ accurate replica of the superman emblem with photoshop http://photoshopmesta.net/1/superman.jpg Didn't make a tutorial though..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that my prior comments might just leave bad taste in your mouth so, I thought it would be only fair that I would give you something more than just "It can be done"

I cleaned up the psd file which contains Note with the same text as below that hopefully explains how it can be done.

[image]

[PSD file can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9245f4vvcj3ye6p/superman.psd?dl=0)

1. First you make the basic base shape(s)

   - I used Pentool to make the base layers.
   - These layers include Base 1 , Base 2 and Base 3
2. Selection layer ( 2nd layer )

   - I sometimes make layers that I can use to quickly get selections from important things.
   - You can do that by clicking the layer thumbnail wile pressing Ctrl. ( In this case the Layer mask thumbnail )
   - This Selection layer has a little feather ( blur ) in the edge.
3. Basic highlights and shadows.

   - These I made straight into Base 1 , Base 2 and Base 3 Layers with Dodge Tool.
   - I used Soft round brush with varying sizes.
   - Opacity from around 10% to 30% ( with a mouse )
   - I use alt to turn Dodge Tool into Burn Tool when I want to darken.
   - I used the Selection layer ( 2nd layer ) to make it easier to highlight and shadow the ridge.
   - Selection can be Inverted with Ctrl+Shift+I.
   - First layer is example of the Dodge tool highlights and shadows.
   - Forgot to mention that Dodge tool is set to Highlight
   - It's also good to take it easy with dodgetool, build up little by little with low opacity.
4. Two big S highlights.

   - Layers with name ( S - Highlight )
   - Done with Brush tool using Soft round brush with varying sizes.
   - Used eraser tool a little in the top highlight.
   - Basic idea is that the lowest of these highlights has the Blend mode as normal and it has a little Yellowish color in it and this layer is little bigger than the highlights above it.
   - Highlight layers above the lowest highlight have white color.
   - These are all in Clipping mask with Base 1 layer so that they will stay inside it.
   - Clipping mask can be done by pointing cursor between layers and clicking there while holding Alt button. Cursor appearance should change if youre howing the cursor in right spot. ( ...while holding Alt button down )
5. Edge highlights. ( a group with the same name )

   - I took these from the Base 1 layers drop shadow that I made into layer.
   - You can do that by opening the Effects ( Fx ) list and right clicking to one of the layer styles and choosing Create layers.
   - Basically I made selections with Polygonal Lasso Tool and made them into separate layers with Ctrl+Shift+J
   - Then inverted the color from black to white Ctrl+I
   - Added Blend modes and duplicated the layers and parts of the layers to get what I wanted.
   - Also I used Eraser tool a bit to soften out some edges of these highlights - Soft round brush of course.

Comment: Thank you, Lollero. I usually participate in StackOverflow discussions about software development, and people there are much less likely to provide such a nice step by step tutorial as an answer. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop: Layers Palette, double click on a layer to bring up Layer Style, choose Bevel and Emboss, go to town.

Answer (score 0):

Those effects weren't added to a flat logo. That 3D logo was drawn that way...either in 2D by a talented illustrator or rendered in a 3D modelling application (or, more than likely, a combination of the two).

Lauren Ipsum is correct in that there are some basic filters in Photoshop that might get you a bit further down the path, but they're certainly not magic and will not get you very close to the bottom example alone.